# C++ Input takes me back to options page infinitely

Tags: c++, for-loop, input, infinite

First of all sorry for what is probably a completely noob question. The problem here is that after I enter in the program of study and press ENTER I am booted back into the options menu. The option menu is seemingly then outputted infinitely. I assume its a buffer error but I just can't figure it out.

int main()
{

```
//Setting max length of the name data entered to 20
string data = " ";
int n = 0,  option = 0, nCount = 0;

//Initial subject mark
string empty = "00";
string programme =  " ";
string department = " ";
char level = ' ';

//Name of file in which database is stored
ifstream f("SDB.txt");
string line;

//For loop counts total number of lines in the file
 for (int i = 0; std::getline(f, line); ++i) {
    nCount++;
}

//The option page
while (option != 5) {
    cout << "\nPlease choose an option\n"
    "1. Add new students\n"
    "2. Student Login\n"
    "3. Staff Login\n"
    "4. Admin View\n"
    "5. Exit\n"
    "Enter option: ";

    cin >> option;

    //What happens when you select each option
    if (option == 1){
    

cout << "Enter the number of students:` ";
cin >> n;

    nCount = nCount + n;


    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        ofstream outfile;
        outfile.open("SDB.txt", ios::app);

    //Stores the entire data of a student
        cout << "Please enter your student ID number: ";
        cin >> data;
        outfile << data << "\t";

        cout << "Please enter your first name: ";
        cin >> data;
        outfile << data << "\t";

        cout << "Please enter your last name: ";
        cin >> data;
        outfile << data << "\t";

        int len = data.length();
    //Check the length of the entered name
        while (len < 30) {
        data[len] = ' ';
        len = len + 1;
        }
        outfile << data << "\n";

        cout << "Please enter your term of study e.g. 2020/24: ";
        cin >> data;
        outfile << data << "\t";

        //Joins you up under a Programme of study
        cout << "Please enter the Programme of study you are in: ";
        getline(cin, programme, '\n');
        cin.ignore();
        outfile << programme << "\t";

        //Inserts empty data into the file initially
        outfile << empty << "\t";
        outfile << empty << "\t";
        outfile << empty << "\t";
        outfile << empty << "\t";

        cout << "Please enter which level of study you are in(C, I or H): ";
        cin >> level;
        outfile << level << endl;
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't include all your code, but the thing about growing the length of your data string out to 30 characters is unsafe. This is not how you modify a string. Instead of this:

```
data[len] = ' ';
```

You can do this:

```
data += " ";
```

It's possible this is the source of some of your trouble, but you're into undefined behavior doing what you're trying to do.